# SwipeGesture Help? Only LeftSwipe Works but RightSwipe does not

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, swipe, gesture

What happens is; when i swipe left the textView changes frame size which is what i want it to do but when i swipe right the textView does not change back to the way i want it, in fact it does not change at all!
Any help?

```
// Add swipeGestures
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *SwipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeReconised:)];
    [SwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:SwipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *SwipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeReconised:)];
    [SwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:SwipeRight];
}
- (void)swipeReconised:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)Swipe {
if (Swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    CGRect frame = [TextView frame];
    frame.size.width = 750;//Some value
    frame.size.height = 655;//some value
    frame.origin.x = 275;
    frame.origin.y = 44;
    [TextView setFrame:frame];
if (Swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    CGRect frame = [TextView frame];
    frame.size.width = 240;//Some value
    frame.size.height = 655;//some value
    frame.origin.x = 784;
    frame.origin.y = 44;
    [TextView setFrame:frame];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening prase of `if (Swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)` should be closed before `if (Swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)` then only it gets call

```
- (void)swipeReconised:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)Swipe {
if (Swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    CGRect frame = [TextView frame];
    frame.size.width = 750;//Some value
    frame.size.height = 655;//some value
    frame.origin.x = 275;
    frame.origin.y = 44;
    [TextView setFrame:frame];
}
if (Swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    CGRect frame = [TextView frame];
    frame.size.width = 240;//Some value
    frame.size.height = 655;//some value
    frame.origin.x = 784;
    frame.origin.y = 44;
    [TextView setFrame:frame];
    }
}
```